# How to read a file and build a Data Structure based on the input file using C++?

Tags: c++, data-oriented-design

I guess this should be possible. I tried but could not find a good answer. I basically want to make a dynamic structure. I want to read a file which tells me the datatypes that my structure will contain. Based on that values I want to build a structure. I want to use C++ for this. We can think of oracle as an example for this where we give a csv file and it recognizes what type they should be and makes columns of that particular datatype.

Can anyone please help me with this problem ?

An Update: I guess I should have added little bit of code to explain my problem statement. So here we go:

```
//PLC Data Block Sturcture.
//Todo: try to construct this structure from a file or something
struct MMSDataHeader{
    bool          bHeader_Trigger;      //2
    unsigned char MachineTimeStamp[8];  //8
    std::string   Header_MachineID;     //12
    std::string   Header_Station;       //12
    int           Header_MessageID;     //2
    int           Header_MessageSequenceNo; //2
    int           Header_NumberOfProperties; //2
    int           MeasurementType;          //2
    bool          Response_Acknowledge;     //2
};
typedef struct MMSDataHeader MMSDataHeader;

int PLCBox::GetHeader(){

   MMSDataHeader local_PLCData = { 0 };
  int res = -1;

  std::cout << "Reading Head :";
  if ((p_s7Client_ == NULL))  {
    std::cerr << "TSnap7Client is not connected.\n";
  }

  res = p_s7Client_->DBRead(nb_db_num_, 0, k_header_size, (void *)(&buffer_));    
  //synchronous mode: default mode
  //inFile.read(buffer_, sizeof(buffer_));
  memcpy(&local_PLCData.bHeader_Trigger, buffer_, 1);
  memcpy(local_PLCData.MachineTimeStamp, buffer_ + 2, 8);
  memcpy(&local_PLCData.Header_MachineID, buffer_ + 10, 12);
  memcpy(&local_PLCData.Header_Station, buffer_ + 22, 12);
  memcpy(&local_PLCData.Header_MessageID, buffer_ + 34, 2);
  memcpy(&local_PLCData.Header_MessageSequenceNo, buffer_ + 36, 2);
  memcpy(&local_PLCData.Header_NumberOfProperties, buffer_ + 39, 2);
  memcpy(&local_PLCData.MeasurementType, buffer_ + 40, 2);
  memcpy(&local_PLCData.Response_Acknowledge, buffer_ + 42, 1);

  nb_props = local_PLCData.Header_NumberOfProperties;
  _b_read_trigger = local_PLCData.bHeader_Trigger;

  return local_PLCData.Header_NumberOfProperties;
}
```

This code works for me now and solves my purpose when I call GetHeader . As you all can see it is looking for exact bytes and structure from the PLCs. I want to make a system such that the structure can be made from a file such that onle a file should be replaced and then the system should work on its own. I think I can explore some things about factory Design pattern to do this. Right now I can determine the type of file and content of the file for my Data structure Construction. Has anyone done something similar on there side.

Comment: I don't think it is possible, C++ needs to know the types at compile time; There are answers around here that says you could use boost variant and other meta-programming tricks.

Comment: You need some way represent each type of data and a container to hold it.

Comment: What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ factory design pattern".

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: Thanks yes I am looking for that answer actually. I am working on that. Direct me if you have any good examples that can solve my problem.

Comment: You can't copy `std::string` the way you are.

Comment: @RetiredNinja: But it works. at least in Windows machine and in Visual Studio

Comment: Lots of things that are incorrect may seem to work fine, but someday they won't. Like assuming the size of those variables will never change and hardcoding them rather than using `sizeof`. Those strings contain pointers to data. If you're saving and reloading them, so you think just copying the pointers is going to bring that data back? It isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It is unlikely to be possible to build C++ data types at runtime because C++ is a statically typed language. You'd better use Python or another dynamically typed language. However, if you think about the problem as about a task of finding a value associated with a key, it is doable, but the resulting "structures" will be nowhere close as fast as statically defined C++ types.

For single-level structures (no sub-structures) you can use a whatever sort of key->value class you would want something along these lines: `std::map<std::string, std::pair<type, std::uniq_ptr<...>>>`. That is, keys as strings are mapped to pairs where the first pair member identifies the value's type, and the second holds a generic pointer to value itself. Provided that there is limited number of types you want to support, you can write a dynamic dispatcher that casts references to actual data types for stored values.

If the input types are allowed to contain sub-structures, things become more complicated. But given that languages for semi-structured data exist (see XML, JSON etc.), you can find a ready solution for arbitrarily complex structured data.

Comment: The key value pair idea was coming to my mind too. Thanks for the direction. Thanks. I have updated my Question a bit with my code that I am currently doing

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can almost always do something - but you might be using the wrong language. C++ is strongly typed, as Max is pointing out - other languages, for example, PHP are not - and can actually change type.  What you could do, which is like rolling your own language, is to override your math operators like +, -, etc so that you have a base class which takes data - and determines if it is float,string, integer, etc and then you use the object like it was a number.  They will all be objects in your structure, but overrides for math, etc.  A lot of work to do this - but there are examples out there regarding overriding math operators, etc.

Comment: yes I have done it in python. but currently in my project I need to do it in C++. :(

Answer (score 0):

As the others said, it cannot be done, at least not in the way that you end up with a structure or class with the member variables with the correct types.

What you can do is parse the file and guess the data type from the format of the value, then create the corresponding type (you have to implement that for all the types you want to support), and finally define a data structure that stores all values with their different types (e.g. a vector with the position as index and using boost::any for the values).

As a side note:
Be aware that you can end up with different types for values at the same position, e.g. if a value is once written as '123' and once as '83.45'. The first value would probably stored as some kind of integer, while the second would result in a float or double.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I have got an idea now. I will take the datatype name and number of bytes from a file and handle it in the way everybody suggested. Thanks alot.